# EaselJS Image created as circle

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm struggling making an image in EaselJS become circular.

Basically, I'm looking for the CSS3 equivalent of `border-radius` in EaselJS and can't find the solution.

The closest I've gotten to this is creating a circle Shape, and adding a `BitmapFill` to it... the problem I'm seeing is that the `BitmapFill` is stuck at an `(0, 0)` x/y position behind the circle Shape, and when I move the Shape to anywhere outside the image size, the `Bitmap` doesn't follow (or **snap**) to the Shape and move with it.

---

Check my [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/skplunkerin/5L79jxgw/8/)

If you change the Circle **x position** to `50`, it looks normal'ish... but notice how moving the Circle away further from `(50, 50)` x/y position that the `Bitmap` gets left behind instead of following.

See below for how my HTML/CSS/Javascript look in the Fiddle:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- CreateJS CDN -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="stage-canvas" width="300" height="300">
  This web browser does not support canvas.
</canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
canvas {
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: block;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Self running function (once page loads)
(function(){
  // preload image assets first with preloadJS
  // used from example here: http://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/modules/PreloadJS.html
  var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
  queue.on("complete", loaded, this);
  queue.loadManifest([
     {id: "poke", src:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Bulbasaur_pokemon_red.png"}
  ]);

  // once images above preloaded, run this function:
  function loaded() {
    // Init Stage
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("stage-canvas")

    // Create Background
    var bg1 = new createjs.Shape()
    bg1.graphics.beginFill("ghostwhite") // first bg is white
    bg1.graphics.drawRect(
      0,                    // x position
      0,                    // y position
      stage.canvas.width,   // width of shape (in px)
      stage.canvas.height   // height of shape (in px)
    )
    // Can only define this after shape is drawn, else no fill applies
    bg1.graphics.ef()    // short for endFill()
    stage.addChild(bg1)  // Add Child to Stage

    // trying to create image to be circlular
    // this will add it as the background-image to a circle
    // but I'm having problems getting it to "snap" to the circle
    // instead of stuck at (0, 0) x/y position behind circle...?
    var circle = new createjs.Shape()
    circle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(
      queue.getResult("poke"), // image to be used as fill
      "no-repeat" // image repeating or not
    )
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(
      150, // x position
      50, // y position
      50 // diameter (in px)
    )
    stage.addChild(circle)

    stage.update()
    }
})()
```

Thank you in advance to helping me figure out how to either fix my code, or if I'm on the wrong path here.

---

**UPDATE:** I originally asked this question for doing a circle image, or an image with rounded corners. I was really only needing the circle image approach, and since provided answers only targeted this, I've removed my question also asking for a rounded corners solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mask` property (http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html#property_mask) on a `Bitmap` to achieve rounded corners.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById('canvas'));

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var container = new createjs.Container();

    var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
    bitmap.regX = bitmap.regY = 150;
    bitmap.y = bitmap.x = 150;

    var maskShape = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().f("#000").drawCircle(150,150,150));
    bitmap.mask = maskShape;

    container.addChild(bitmap);

    stage.addChild(container);
    stage.update();

    container.x = container.y = 50;

    stage.update();
};
img.src = '//unsplash.it/300/300';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2tsym49r/3/

**Edit**:
As mentioned by Lanny `mask` is using the Canvas `clip` method and thus won't be antialiased in Chrome (open bug). If you need antialiasing in Chrome you can do a workaround using compositeOperation, check the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2tsym49r/4/

Comment: Mask is great (and the most performant), however note that it will not be antialiased in Chrome. The bitmap fill approach gets around that.

Comment: I really prefer this mask approach, but this still causes the same issue I'm experiencing when trying to move x/y positions: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/skplunkerin/2tsym49r/2/). Any idea how to also fix that @derz?

Comment: also @derz, your jsfiddle needs to be updated to match your code above :) (also add createjs script include so it works)

Comment: I've updated your fiddle (and corrected the link ;-)). https://jsfiddle.net/2tsym49r/3/ However I'm not sure, why the mask isn't relative to the bitmap - I thought it should be. @Lanny Am I wrong with that?

Comment: And another update to get antialiasing in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/2tsym49r/4/ However I'm also not sure here, what's faster - using the composite-operation workaround or bitmapFill. Maybe @Lanny did some performance tests?

Comment: Nice addition. I have not benchmarked the difference, but compositeOperation might be faster. It does result in 2 draws though.

Comment: @derz can you update your answer with your newest jsfiddle link/code? I'm really liking the mask approach best and want your newest jsfiddle as the acceptable answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend centering the circle, and using a matrix to also center the bitmapfill.

```
// Create a matrix
var matrix = new createjs.Matrix2D()
    .translate(-160/2, -144/2); // Move to 50% the width and height of the image

circle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(
  queue.getResult("poke"), // image to be used as fill
  "no-repeat",
  matrix // Pass in the matrix
);

// Draw the circle at 0,0
circle.graphics.drawCircle(
  0, // x position
  0, // y position
  50 // diameter (in px)
);

// Move it to wherever you want
circle.x = 100;
circle.y = 100;
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/md73ns53/

You could also scale the matrix to make the image fit the circle.

Comment: Thanks @Lanny, I'm trying to grasp what exactly the Matrix is doing for us here? Could you explain that? ( I'm pretty math deficit :P ) I don't understand how that "just fixes this"?

Comment: The matrix just tells the fill to transform by a specific amount (scale, rotation, translation). Since you just want to move (translate) the coordinates, I used the `translate` method, moving it half the width and height of the image (-w/2, -h/2). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the circle Shape into a Container, and then moving the Container where you want it should do it. This is currently the only option I've found:

[See this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skplunkerin/q8o9vayf/1/)

**Change this:**

```
var circle = new createjs.Shape()
circle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(
  queue.getResult("poke"), // image to be used as fill
  "no-repeat" // image repeating or not
)
circle.graphics.drawCircle(
  150, // x position
  50, // y position
  50 // diameter (in px)
)
stage.addChild(circle)
```

**To this:**

```
var circle = new createjs.Shape()
circle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(
  queue.getResult("poke"), // image to be used as fill
  "no-repeat" // image repeating or not
)
circle.graphics.drawCircle(
  50, // x position
  50, // y position
  50 // diameter (in px)
)
// Create a container for the circle
var container = new createjs.Container()
container.x = 150
container.y = 150
container.addChild(circle) // add circle to container
stage.addChild(container) // then add container to stage
```